# How do I set the X and Y of the System Preferences window?

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to open the System Preferences and then position it to the right or left edge (without changing it's size). I'm keep getting errors:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to set x and y to 20
```

Error:

```
Can’t set x and y to 20. Access not allowed.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the position of the window by using the `bounds` property.

```
set {x, y} to {0, 22} -- position
tell application "System Preferences"
    tell (get bounds of window 1) to set {tRig, tBot} to {(item 3) - ((item 1) - x), (item 4) - ((item 2) - y)}
    set bounds of window 1 to {x, y, tRig, tBot} -- change position of the window without changing it's size
end tell
```

Comment: Nice one! Didn't know about this way!

Comment: This is more to ask and not sure if it warrants a new question but would you know how position it 20 pixels to the right edge of the screen?

Comment: Due to better code formatting a new question should be better, but you you need to get the coordinates of the desktop first. After that you can calculate starting at the x coordinate. Give this a try: `set {xDiff, yAbs} to {500, 1000}
tell application "Finder" to tell (get bounds of window of desktop) to set rightEdge to item 3
tell application "System Preferences"
 activate
 tell (get bounds of window 1) to set {tWid, tHei} to {(item 3) - (item 1), (item 4) - (item 2)}
 set bounds of window 1 to {rightEdge - xDiff - tWid, yAbs, rightEdge - xDiff, yAbs + tHei}
end tell`

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the app "System Events" to access the running processes and UI elements. I end up with a solution like:

```
tell application "System Preferences" to activate

tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        tell first window
            set position to {100, 100}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Have fun! Michael / Hamburg